# modify one of jira classes with aspectj

Tags: java, jira, aspectj

I'm trying to fix jira bug by modifying class
com.atlassian.jira.issue.util.IssueImplAggregateTimeTrackingCalculator using aspectj with compile time weaving

To do this I

- create plugin with atlassian SDK (just to get all necessary jira dependencies in project
- install aspectj plugin to my   intellij
- put aspectj dependencies and aspectj-maven-plugin to pom
- create package com.atlassian.jira.issue.util where put the source java class IssueImplAggregateTimeTrackingCalculator I want to modify along with new CalculatorFix.aj aspect class

then I compile the project and copy 2 compiled classes from targer folder to WEB-INF/classes of my jira instance

behaviour is not modified

what am I doing wrong?

here is the relevant part of my pom

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- might not be necessary cuz i put aspectj to project libs -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <!-- for aspectj support -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${aspectj-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <complianceLevel>1.8</complianceLevel>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                    <Xlint>ignore</Xlint>
                    <encoding>UTF-8 </encoding>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <!-- use this goal to weave all your main classes -->
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <!-- use this goal to weave all your test classes -->
                            <!--
                            <goal>test-compile</goal>
                            -->
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        <plugin>
```

here is the IssueImplAggregateTimeTrackingCalculator I'm trying to modify

```
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.Issue;
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.MutableIssue;
import com.atlassian.jira.security.JiraAuthenticationContext;
import com.atlassian.jira.security.PermissionManager;
import com.atlassian.jira.security.Permissions;

import java.util.Collection;


public class IssueImplAggregateTimeTrackingCalculator implements AggregateTimeTrackingCalculator {
    private final PermissionChecker permissionChecker;

    public IssueImplAggregateTimeTrackingCalculator(final JiraAuthenticationContext context, final PermissionManager permissionManager) {
        this(new PermissionChecker() {
            public boolean hasPermission(Issue subTask) {
                return permissionManager.hasPermission(Permissions.BROWSE, subTask, context.getUser());
            }
        });
    }

    public IssueImplAggregateTimeTrackingCalculator(PermissionChecker permissionChecker) {
        this.permissionChecker = permissionChecker;
    }

    
    public AggregateTimeTrackingBean getAggregates(Issue issue) {
        // here is the code I want to modify
    }

   
    public interface PermissionChecker {
        boolean hasPermission(Issue subTask);
    }
}
```

here is my aspect class

```
package com.atlassian.jira.issue.util;

import com.atlassian.jira.issue.Issue;

public privileged aspect CalculatorFix {

    pointcut callGetAggregates(Issue issue,
                               IssueImplAggregateTimeTrackingCalculator issueImplAggregateTimeTrackingCalculator) :
            call(AggregateTimeTrackingBean com.atlassian.jira.issue.util.IssueImplAggregateTimeTrackingCalculator.getAggregates(Issue))
            && args(issue)
            && target(issueImplAggregateTimeTrackingCalculator);

    AggregateTimeTrackingBean around (Issue issue,
                                      IssueImplAggregateTimeTrackingCalculator issueImplAggregateTimeTrackingCalculator):
            callGetAggregates(issue, issueImplAggregateTimeTrackingCalculator) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("hello AspectJ world");
    }
}
```

Comment: This is hard to answer without me seeing your situation live, like I could as a (hired) consultant. I neither have access to the Atlassian SDK nor to a local Jira instance. I am also unsure if you really replaced the original Jira class by the woven one or tried to add it on top of some other class which still exists in a JAR and might be loaded before your own class is even found. Moreover, did you make sure that _aspectjrt.jar_ is on the classpath for the Jira app? Maybe load-time weaving would actually be easier for you, but if done right, this approach should also work.

Comment: thank you for useful hints. Actually I'm completly new to AspectJ and have chousen compile-time weaving for my first try cuz the doc says: "Compile-time weaving is the simplest approach". I'll try to dig into the way Atlassian Jira loads it's core classes to check if I put my compiled classes to the right place. Second thing I've missed for shure is aspectj.jar in Jira classpath. Will put it there and try once again/